# What does "hung an entire history on him" mean?

Tags: john-le-carre, smileys-people

From John Le Carre's *Smiley's People*:

> At a crucial moment, an unknown man turned round and looked at me and I hung an entire history on him, even imagining he was my dying father.

Background: "I" refer to the young man acting as a courier for the general. The "unknown man" was sent by the general to get the picture and deliver that via the young man.

My understanding was that the picture was so important that it might alter history, which depended on that unknown man.

Comment: The unknown man is like a hanger on which the young hangs a history, not a coat or shirt. ["I" refer*s*] Also, to hang something on someone in colloquial English means: to ascribe something to someone.

Comment: @Lambie So what does "history" means exactly here? Does that mean the young man's personal past or something else?

Comment: a person's background, his or her history. What's your history exactly? Have you always been an X?

Comment: @Lambie still it does not make much sense to me. Why the young man felt like his personal history was determined by or linked with that unknown man? I don't quite get it.

Comment: Not the 'young man's' history, but the 'unknown man's'.

Comment: [Simple past: Why did x feel like his personal history, etc.] I can say anything I like as an author. I don't need to check with anyone. Haven't you ever seen a person and imagined all sorts of things about them? It's important to believe a narrative even if you see the world differently. John Le Carré is not easy to understand. He's very literary and very referential.

Comment: @Lambie, yes, an author can write whatever he likes. But what he writes should be logical, not hard to understand, and not confusing. Readers shouldn't have to make guess and solve riddles. I don't think this kind of narrative is the best part of Le Carré's works.

Comment: So you're a native speaker right? But although you've talked a lot, you still didn't explain whose history that referred to. Are you really clear of its meaning? @KateBunting said it's the "unknown man's" history. Do you think he's a native speaker or not?

Comment: I'm a she, and, yes, I am a native speaker.  The passage says "**I** hung an entire history on **him**" - the speaker imagined a past history for the unknown man.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you for your comments. I was asking Lambie, not you. Sorry for typing by mistake 'he' instead of 'she'. Also before this sentence the young man didn't mention much about the unknown man's history (in his imagination). So it's kind of confusing.

Comment: I thought you were asking Lambie whether I was a native speaker. The sentence appears to be the first reference to the imaginary past history, so I wouldn't expect it to have been mentioned before. The pronouns make it clear who is 'hanging' the history on whom.

Comment: @KateBunting I would choose yours as the best answer for my question if you put it as an 'Answer' rather than a 'Comment'. Thanks again.

Comment: You know I reread my comments to you and Kate's answer in which she says the same thing as me. "a person's background, his or her history" would be the same as "a complete past history".

Comment: @Lambie maybe you're right that you basically just said the same thing as Kate's. But to me, a non-native speaker, Kate's answer is more straightforward and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The young man ("I")says that when he first saw the "unknown man" he imagined a complete past history (life story) for him. The pronouns *I* and *him* make it clear who is doing the "hanging".

Answer (score 1):

The unknown man, who we will later learn is named Otto Leipzig, has a striking appearance that gives him a sort of aura of mystery. (Madame Ostrakova gives him the nickname “the Magician.”) He exchanges this look with Max, and Max is inspired to imagine a background story for this mysterious man.

(There are several places in the Smiley novels where perception and imagination set the spies apart from ordinary people, and this is one of them.)

Comment: I agree. But this kind of imagination sometimes seems far-fetched, not very logical, and confusing.